# Find where my Gmail account is used for registration?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Gmail account that I use for official purposes and another account for signing up to various sites. How do I find to which sites I have given my Gmail ID?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends upon what you mean by "given my Gmail ID"

If you signed up to those sites using your email address and created a password, then your inbox or archive should have messages from those sites verifying your registration.

If you instead used your Google ID to log in to these sites "with Google" authentication, here are the easy steps to find these sites:

1. Sign in to https://www.google.com/settings/security
2. In the "Account permissions" box, next to **Apps and websites** select [View all](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).

This section will list all of the sites with account permissions.  This works for regular Gmail accounts as well as Google Apps accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this only if you get an automated reply (or) confirmation message from the respective website and you can perform manual search. Now the GMail ID which you used for signing up to websites is just like open source id and many website would have this ID in their database but GMail will have the reference only if it gets reply from those website.

Hope this helps!